# Deleting Empty cell arrays

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have created cell arrays and put values using the loop.. Here is what I have done:

```
mycell =cell(1,100,num);       %% assume num anything
idx = 1;
[a,b] = size(depth);
for i=1:a
 for j=1:b
      if isfinite(depth(i,j)) 
      for segId=1:2
        mycell{:,idx,segId} = depth(i,j);
        idx=idx+1;
```

In the end i got result like this:

```
mycell(;,:,1) = 
[1] [1.2] [1.222] [] [] [] [0.7] [06] [] [0.34] .....[100n]

mycell(;,:,2) = 
[] [] [] [1.33] [0.5] [0.3] [] [] [0.5] [] .....[100n]
```

Is there any way I can delete the empty cell in these cell arrays...

Or is there any way I can get an output like this: - 
[1*9 values][1*88 values] and so on... like on cell array and get values in one cell...I am unable to do this because of this loop.

Comment: `mycell(cellfun(@isempty, mycell)) = []` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove empty cells, is trivial (Similar to [Luis's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36142667/deleting-empty-cell-arrays/36142807#comment59923385_36142667)). Essentially this calls `isempty` on each cell element and then uses this logical array to index into `mycell` and retrieve only the non-empty values.

```
newcell = mycell(cellfun(@isempty, mycell));
```

However, you mention combining multiple elements into a single element. You can do this by using `{:}` expansion. What this essentially does is expand all elements that you have indexed into separate inputs. So if we make these the inputs to [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html), we can concatenate all of the elements along the specified dimension.

Just to demonstrate:

```
a = {1, 2, 3};
cat(2, a{:});

    [1 2 3]
```

So in your data, we could easily combine all data along the first index of the third dimension:

```
item = cat(2, mycell{:,:,1});
```

We can also do this to completely flatten your data along the third dimension.

```
newcell = arrayfun(@(x)cat(2, mycell{:,:,x}), 1:size(mycell, 3), 'uni', 0);
```

If you take this second approach, you don't even have to worry about first removing empty cells as they will just disappear during concatenation.

```
a = {1, 2, 3, [], 4};
cat(2, a{:});

    [1  2  3  4]
```

Comment: Thank You. "isempty" functions was not working. It removes all the empty cells but was combining the result of mycell(:,:,1) and mycell(:,:,2) into one ans, therefore I asked this question here. The last approach of your has solved the problem.

Comment: As the previous result I have achieved like [1*9 single] and so on...Is it any way I can have convert them in matrix, i.e. every single cell into different matrix. ?

Comment: @Akash Yes you can use `num2cell`. `m = num2cell(data)`

Comment: I have defined my cell as (1,100,2) so it has 1 row, 100 columns..and I am getting result as [1*9 single]. after using num2cell, I am getting values as column 1till 9 = [1][1][1]...and so on... Is it possible to get output as 3 dimensional..something like [2*2*2] or anything. I want output as xyz format so that I can treat it as an input to RANSAC